# Relationship with Google's "Get the answer you’re looking for added to the web"?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, google

This morning as I googled for something I noticed something new at the bottom of the search results:

[image: Get the answer you’re looking for added to the web]

Clicking on "learn more" brings up this:

[image: Contents of learn more link]

Is SE one of those "publishers" with access to the submitted questions?

Is Google's effort going to take some traffic from SE?

Comment: "Is SE one of those "publishers" with access to the submitted questions?" - No

Comment: The functionality is called Google Question Hub.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google is trying to tap into some of the Quora / SE market and enable users to find the answers to their questions directly from the Google search box. I'd imagine this will definitely impact SE traffic when fully rolled out.

Comment: Google has explicitly stated that contributing to it will not help your SEO rankings.  But yes, it will impact the traffic presuming that people will be less likely to follow google search results and otherwise opt for the google answers.